# Defining a schema for response with multiple lines

Tags: schema, response, raml

I am areal newby on RAML. I'm trying to define a schema for a response that will contain multiple lines, just like a resultset in SQL. I have done this but just for one line responses.

I also would like to define an example.

Can you help me with some examples of how to acheive this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of inline schema :-

```
#%RAML 0.8
title: A one-song API
/{songId}:
  get:
    body:
      application/json:
        schema: |
          {
            "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema",
            "type": "object",
            "description": "The canonical song representation",
            "properties": {
              "title":  { "type": "string" },
              "artist": { "type": "string" }
            },
            "required": [ "title", "artist" ]
          }
```

The `|` pipe symbol, which allows spanning a string scalar across multiple lines.
ref:- https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/issues/8